# Surjectivity of bundle projection

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles

In some textbooks, a fiber bundle is defined as follows: for topological spaces $E$, $B$ and $F$, we say that a continuous map $\pi \colon E \to B$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $F$ if for any point $b \in B$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $b$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is homeomorphic to $U \times F$ via some map $\varphi$ which satisfies $p_1 \circ \varphi=\pi|_{\pi^{-1}(U)}$. Here $p_1$ is the projection to the first factor.

I noticed that in some textbooks, a fiber bundle requires $\pi$ moreover to be surjective. I wonder if this surjectivity is necessary. I presume that if $B$ is path-connected, then the surjectivity follows from parallel transport. If not, I guess that there is an example of a fiber bundle in the sense of the above definition missing surjectivity. Is there such an example? Or, does the sutjectivity follow from the definition unless $F$ is empty?

I would also like to know the situation we really need the surjectivity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assume the existence of the neighbourhood $U$ of $b$ homeomorphic to $U\times F$ an such that $p_1\circ \varphi=\pi$, you are assuming, also, that you can take any $f\in F$ and consider
$$
(b,f)\in U\times F.
$$

Then, $\varphi^{-1}(b,f)\in E$ is such that
$$
\pi(\varphi^{-1}(b,f))=p_1(b,f)=b,
$$
and therefore $\pi$ is surjective.

Comment: Well, at least as long as the fibre $F$ is nonempty. What you've really proved is that either $\pi$ is surjective or $E$ is empty and no point is in its image.

Comment: That is true, good appreciation

Comment: @A. J. Pan-Collantes If at least one topological space among $E$, $B$ and $F$ is connected, then $\pi$ is surjective by your argument because connectedness implies being nonempty. Am I right?

Comment: Connectedness has nothing to do, at least in the framework you have established. As long as the standard fibre is nonempty you have surjectivity. I think you are getting confuse with something, maybe is with the following fact. If the manifold $M$ is connected, the it can be shown that the fibres are all homemorphic (Lemma 1.1.9 in [Saunders](https://personalnotes.000webhostapp.com/Bibliography/@saunders1989geometry.md.html)). But you are assuming from the beginning that the fibre is always $F$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My concern is not fibers being homeomorphic but the total space being nonempty. For example, if $E$ is connected, then it is nonempty, and so is a fiber; hence by your argument combined with Tyrone's comment, $\pi$ is surjective, isn't it? Maybe connectedness of $B$ is not enough to show the surjectivity of $\pi$.

Comment: The empty space is connected.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a better answer than the statement that, with the definition you put in your post, $\pi$ is surjective if and only $F$ is nonempty. Textbook authors hope they can craft their definitions carefully enough to avoid niche cases such as empty fibers, but sometimes they just miss such cases.

Comment: @Thorgott Right, the empty set is connected! I was confused.

Comment: @LeeMosher Now I see that the surjectivity of $\pi$ is equivalent to the nonemptyness of $F$. In practice, $F$ is non-empty (e.g. $F$ is a group), and hence not assuming the surjectivity of $\pi$ doesn't seem so harmful.